# AVAssetReader samplerate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, ipod

How do I calculate the samplerate of a song obtained from the iPod Library using AVAssetReader. I think I can pretty easily get the amount of samples, ( I am already successfully reading the samples anyways.. ), but I do not know where I can obtain the length ( in seconds ) of the song.

Note that MPMediaItem has no property for the length of the Media Item, maybe there is another way through this API to get the length of the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MPMediaItem` to get the length. Have a look at the `MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration` property key. The docs state:

> The playback duration of the media item. Value is an NSNumber object representing a duration in seconds as an NSTimeInterval.

Comment: No idea how I could have missed that one, checked the documentation. Thanks anyway. However as it turns out I cannot use AVAssetReader this way for my purpose, I only know the amount of samples afterwards, which is too late. Unfortunately when exporting the iPod file to my documents folder ExtAudioFile is returning an error when trying to read the properties of the sound file.

Comment: Have a look at the Audio File Services API. I think you can use the `AudioFileGetProperty()` function with the `kAudioFilePropertyBitRate` key.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235572/extaudiofilegetproperty-failing -- I don't exactly know why its failing

Answer (score 0):

if you are actually still wondering about the sample rate, it is done like so:
Once you have your `AVAssetTrack` you are interested in, you can get the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` and inspect that to find the original sample rate.

```
AVAssetTrack * track = ...;
CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef trackDescription = static_cast<CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef>([track.formatDescriptions firstObject]);
const AudioStreamBasicDescription * trackAsbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(trackDescription);

double sampleRate = trackAsbd->mSampleRate;
```

error checking omitted...